# How to add default generic type - typing createReducer with Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

[Here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/refactoringreducersexample) you can see a handy `createReducer()`
How would you type it using `Flow`?

Here is my example

```
// @flow
import type { TAction as TActionDefault } from '../actions/types';

type THandlers<TState, TAction> = {
  [key: string]: (state: TState, action: TAction) => any
}

type TReducer<TState, TAction> = (state: TState, action: TAction) => TState


export default function createReducer<TState, TAction>(
  initialState: TState,
  handlers: THandlers<TState, TAction>
): TReducer<TState, TAction> {
  return function reducer(state: TState = initialState, action: TAction): TState {
    if (handlers[action.type]) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action)
    } else {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

But there is an issue here

```
Cannot get `action.type` because property `type` is missing in `TAction` [1]. (References: [1])
```

And flow doesn't let me to give default type value to `TAction`.

So what do you do in this and similar cases?

Comment: What is the `TActionDefault` type? Can you add it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow does let you add a default for the generic

```
createReducer<TState, TAction = TActionDefault>
```

The above compiles as of June 2019. See https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6875

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here

`createReducer<TState, TAction>`

I tried to add default value to the generic like this

`createReducer<TState, TAction = TActionDefault>`

Yet this is the correct way.

`createReducer<TState, TAction: TActionDefault>`

So the final code looks like this

```
// @flow
import type { TAction as TActionDefault } from '../actions/types';

type THandlers<TState, TAction> = {
  [key: string]: (state: TState, action: TAction) => TState
}

type TReducer<TState, TAction = any> = (state: TState, action: TAction) => TState


export default function createReducer<TState, TAction: TActionDefault<any>>(
  initialState: TState,
  handlers: THandlers<TState, TAction>
): TReducer<TState, TAction> {
  return function reducer(state: TState = initialState, action: TAction): TState {
    if (handlers[action.type]) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action);
    }
    return state;
  };
}
```

Comment: That's not the correct way. You added a type constraint, not a generic parameter default